# What could be the reason for hibernate transaction commit taking 10 seconds with 100% CPU utilization for every batch?

Tags: java, performance, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are having this issue with our Spring Hibernate JPA web application. We are uploading excel 3000 records using Apache POI into MYSQL. Commit frequency is 10 records, but each commit takes 10 seconds pause and CPU reaches almost 100% throughout the import process. I'm suspecting if there is a memory leak in session(cache) objects. But there is enough space in the young, old and permanent generations of the Java heap. What could be the possible issue? Is there any tools to profile whats happening at the time of commit? Please advise.

Comment: A Profiler would be the tool to use.

Comment: The reason might not even be hibernate/JPA at all, but your application design. What's the performance like if you run the transaction without java?

Comment: Hi Gerrytan, Thank you so much for the response. If we perform the same set of(most) operations directly in the performance, the commit is not pausing. Its completing in acceptable time. While java transaction commit, flush seems to be taking long time. Is there any way(or tool) in which i can see whats in my session cache and why its taking time?

Comment: Some profiling tools you could use would be [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) to see where CPU time is spent and using the [MySQL general query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) to see what statements are actually being executed.